# jQuery .css Background no-repeat

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set the background of an element to `no-repeat` - I've tried the following way but it seems to do nothing, am I going wrong somewhere? It brings out the image on the `a` link which is fine. I'm hiding the text links using `text-indent` to get it off the page (hiding it) but hiding this also hides the background image. Is there a way of trying to hide the link and just display the bg image? Below is what i have done so far - I just need some guidance to overcome this problem - relatively new to jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //Looking for every td a element and alerting it out on page (popup)

$('.AspNet-DataList td a').each(function (index) {
    //alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
    var submitEl = $(".AspNet-DataList td a")
    //.parent('.AspNet-DataList td a')
    .css('background', 'url(/assets/img/radarstep' + (index + 1) + 'dark.png)', 'backgroundRepeat:', 'no-repeat');
});
```

When I view it in firebug the `td a` element this is what is coming from the jQuery css. Even setting the background to `no-repeat` from here doesnt work and in the main css file I have tried adding a height and width - doesn't seem to work. Confused now.

```
<a id="ctl07_HealthAndSafetyRadarForm_Wizard_SideBarContainer_SideBarList_SideBarButton_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl07$HealthAndSafetyRadarForm_Wizard$SideBarContainer$SideBarList$ctl05$SideBarButton','')" style="background: url("/assets/img/radarstep6dark.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;">Review</a>


//main.css
.AspNet-DataList td a {
    /*text-indent: -9999em;*/
    /*display:block;  */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px; 
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
.css({'background-image' : 'url(/assets/img/radarstep' + (index + 1) + 'dark.png)',
      'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'});
```

Comment: Houdmont that worked perfectly - is there documentation on the different properties i can add for the background like height, width, opacity levels? - '.css({ 'background-image': 'url(/assets/img/radarstep' + (index + 1) + 'dark.png)',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'height': '25px',
            'width': '25px'
        });'

Answer (score 2):

Why did you comment the `display: block;` css ? You need that to tell the browser your link has to be displayed as a block. 
Also I'm not sure you can use jQuery `css` properties like you do ; did you try the syntax `div.css( { propertie: value, propertie: value } );` ?

Comment: i initially put a block to hide the text off page for testing purposes. I will try your solution Jeremy. Thanks for taking the time in helping me.

Comment: un-commenting the 'display:block' worked now as it displays the correct height + width =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.css({
    'background-image': 'url(/assets/img/radarstep' + (index + 1) + 'dark.png)',
    'background-repeat' : 'no-repeat'
});
```

Comment: when adding the line it comes back with **Expected: ':'**

Comment: oh silly me, instead of adding the , i should be adding : (sometimes i feel like slapping the eyes out of my head)

Comment: Where you've written 'background-repeat:', it should be 'background-repeat', without the : at the end of the property name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 input[type="submit"] {background:url(mybutton.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;height: 29px;width: 44px; }
```

Try this it works for me